# I need to generate a part of the sequence 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 ... (the number is repeated as many times, to what it equals to)

Tags: java

I got this for homework but I am stuck with understanding the wrongdoing of my code.

Here is the task: **Write a program that prints a part of the sequence 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 ... (the number is repeated as many times, to what it equals to). The input to the program is a positive integer n: the number of the elements of the sequence the program should print. Output the sequence of numbers, written in a single line, space-separated.**

For example, if n = 7, then the program should output 1 2 2 3 3 3 4.

Sample Input 1:

7

Sample Output 1:

### 1 2 2 3 3 3 4

Here is my code (OUTPUT AT BOTTOM:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        

        System.out.println("Enter: );
        int totalNum = scanner.nextInt();
        
        int counter = 0;
        
        for(int i = 1; i <= totalNum; i++){
            for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
                counter++;
                System.out.println(" " + i);
        
            }
            
        }
    }
    
 }
```

Here is my output(Input is 4):

**ALL ON NEW LINE NOT SAME LINE**

```
4
 1
 2
 2
 3
 3
 3
 4
 4
 4
 4
```

Can someone please help me in understanding why my output and the required output differ? :)

Comment: Thank you to anybody willing to help. I am just a naive coder hoping to make outta the Java jam.

Comment: Looks like you are missing a closing double quote after "Enter".

Comment: Please format your console interactions as code. That's how you avoid having to explain how many lines you have

Comment: `n: the number of the elements of the sequence the program should print` so you should compare `totalNum` with `counter`

Comment: This is what `println` does. It prints a new line. You can create a string variable, add number to it on each iteration, then print it. Or use `System.out.print()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need two corrections in your program:

1. Add a closing double quote in line `System.out.println("Enter: );`
2. You also have to change your algorithm. The problem statement asks that you should only print n numbers, but you are printing the sequence 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, ......n,n,n,n. You can add a check that when counter equals n you should break.

```
       boolean shouldBreak = false;
       
       for(int i = 1; i <= totalNum; i++){
           for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
               if(counter == totalNum){
                   shouldBreak = true;
                   break;
               }
               counter++;
               System.out.print(i + " ");
           }
           if(shouldBreak){
               break;
           }
           
       }
```

Comment: You could add a label to the outer loop and then break out of both loops by specifying the label with the break. This would avoid the boolean variable and the if.

Comment: Thanks everybody, in terms of the enter that was a bit of a stupid mistake on my side. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalNum; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}
```

First of all, you should try to learn the meaning of each thing you are writing. For example, why programmer should count from 0 and not 1, what is the difference between `print`and `println`.

**Asking for** help each time you don't understand something is not the issue. But you should ask Google first. Good luck in your learning journey.

Comment: Hmm, how would you get this: "For example, if n = 7, then the program should output 1 2 2 3 3 3 4."

Comment: n = 7 which gives the 7 elements, so your recent comment, thanks!.